# Bluescreen or Explorer.exe freeze when attempting to remove specific files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze, bsod, onedrive

I have a few files stored in a OneDrive folder that I'd like to get rid of.

The first time I tried to delete them (after opening OneDrive settings and disabling "Files on-demand", I don't know if this is relevant), the process got stuck at 35%. It didn't seem like my whole computer was frozen but I was unable to do anything beside restarting the computer by holding the button.
Retrying several times sometimes gave me a Blue Screen saying "page fault in non-paged area".

I tried deleting the files through OneDrive online, but that just made the computer freeze up as soon as OneDrive started syncing.
Uninstalling OneDrive and trying to delete the files also caused a freeze.

I've since reinstalled OneDrive and left the files in place, and my computer works fine now, but I'd still like to remove the files.
Here's a screenshot of the documents, there were a couple more that didn't give me any trouble to remove in the exact same folder:
[image: Unremovable files]

Comment: analyze the dumps with windbg to see what causes the issue: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: I've tried following a guide but I honestly really don't know what specifically to look for, all I know is that it's related to ntfs.sys

Comment: run **chkdsk C: /F** to check the hdd file system for issues

Comment: It reported no problems after scanning the file system

Comment: share the dmp files, maybe I can see more.

Comment: The .dmp file disappeared and I haven't been able to reproduce the Blue Screen since then, only the freezing, I'll update when it works

Comment: press CAPS LOCK during freeze and look if LED on keyboard toggles or not. if it toggles, you have a software based freeze, if you see no light toggle you have a HW issue.

Comment: I can still turn Fn and Caps Lock on or off and move my mouse around, I can even mouseover the icons on my desktop.

Comment: I have no real idea why this happens. open onedrive website and delete the files there, this get synced later to disk.

Comment: I've done this and it causes the computer to freeze when OneDrive starts up

Comment: hm, open a support case at Microsoft. I think this out of scope of this community.

Comment: I was finally able to get a .dmp file: http://www.filedropper.com/122017-9734-01, haven't opened a support case at Microsoft yet

Comment: Windbg says "Could not read faulting driver name" so it could be HW issue. test disk and RAM

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried to delete the files through PowerShell, uninstall onedrive, remove the whole folder and reinstall and it seems to be fixed now... Did get a warning that the files were at an "NTFS junction point"

Comment: dump shows cldflt.sys which is responsibly for the new feature to see data even if they are not on disk and only in cloud

Comment: So the problem was OneDrive after all?

Comment: it is a new feature since 1709, so there could be still bugs. MS removed in in Win10 after 1st version in 8.1 also had issues.